# Why is $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ called a measurable space when actually is not?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I get confused when I put the following three notes together:

1. Power set of any set is a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. If $X$ is a set and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $X$, then the pair $(X, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space.
3. [Vitali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) set is known as a counterexample that there is no measure on all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

By (1) and (2), one may think that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a measurable space, which intuitively concludes that there must be a measure on all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. However, (3) says the opposite. Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: "By (1) and (2), one may think that (ℝ,(ℝ)) is a measurable space, which intuitively concludes that there must be a measure on all the subsets of ℝ" I don't know any definition in mathematics that intuitively concludes anything. You may need to review the definition of a measurable space; it does not mention a "measure" at all. (Of course there is a measure on all the subsets of $\mathbb R,$ counting measure for one. But that's beside the point.)

Comment: You wrote : "Vitali set is known as a counterexample that there is no measure on all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$".   IT IS NOT TRUE.   Vitali set  just shows that  there is no measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that: 1.  $\mu$ is countable additive 2. for all open interval (a,b), $\mu((a,b))= b-a$ AND 3. $\mu$ is invariant by translation.  

There are several countable additive measures defined on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. For instance, the counting measure $\sharp$.

Comment: Given any measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, there is at least one measure that can be defined on $(X,\Sigma)$ and make it a measure space. One of such measures is the counting measure $\sharp$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an unfortunate choice of terminology.

- The term ***measureable space***, taken as a single unit, is **defined** to mean a set $X$ with a chosen sigma-algebra $\Sigma$. There is no specific choice of measure involved, and saying that $(X,\Sigma)$ is a measurable space is **not intended** to claim that it is possible to define a measure with that set and that sigma-algebra (even though, as it turns out, it is always possible: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)).
  Therefore it is absolutely correct to say that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a "measurable space", but you should not take that as saying anything about a specific measure, or even whether it is possible to define a measure, despite the typical semantics of the word "measurable".
- When we say that the Vitali set $V$ is "non-measurable", that is (implicitly) taken to mean with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue sigma-algebra $\mathscr{L}$. In other words, it is a claim that $V\notin \mathscr{L}$.
   The Vitali set is **not** a counterexample to what you said, because it **is possible** to define a measure on the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, as I pointed out earlier ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)). 
   The **correct** statement is that the Vitali set shows that one cannot define a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ **that also satsifies certain desired properties** (such as $\mu((a,b))=b-a$, among others.) It is **absolutely possible** to define a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$ that does **not** have those nice properties.

Comment: Imo "measurable spaces" should really have been called "$\sigma$-spaces" or "$\sigma$-algebra spaces" or something like that.

Comment: I think "measurable space" is good terminology. It's ready to be measured.

Answer (score 2):

the reason for your confusion could be, that you forgot some conditions for 3.

Vitali sets are a counterexample that there is no measure on all the subsets of $\mathbb R$ with the following conditions:

1. the measure of an open interval (a,b) should be b-a
2. the measure should be invariant w.r.t to translation
3. the measure is countable additive

Comment: 3.the measure is countably additive.